# I am unsure how to list invalid octets if there are others that are valid

Tags: java, jgrasp

I need to print a hypothetical IP address. I must print if all 4 octets are within range, but I do not know how to print if 1 or more octets aren't.

My teacher's instructions:

> You are going to write a program that will accept 4 integer numbers from a user, check to see if they are valid IP address range numbers `(1 - 255).(0 - 255).(0 - 255).(1 - 254)` and then if they are valid you will put them in the correct dotted decimal notation for an IP address.
> If they are invalid, tell the user which one is invalid.
>
> Sample Run:
>
> ```
> Please enter the first Octet:
> 125
> Please enter the second Octet:
> 10
> Please enter the third Octet:
> 52
> Please enter the fourth Octet:
> 10
> IP Address: 125.10.52.10
> ```
>
> Sample Run:
>
> ```
> Please enter the first Octet:
> 125
> Please enter the second Octet:
> 10
> Please enter the third Octet:
> 520
> Please enter the fourth Octet:
> 10
> Octet three is incorrect.
> ```

What I have tried:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the first Octet:");
int oct1;
oct1 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the second Octet:");
int oct2;
oct2 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the third Octet:");
int oct3;
oct3 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the fourth Octet:");
int oct4;
oct4 = scan.nextInt();
if (oct1 >= 1 && oct1 <= 255);{
    System.out.println("Octet one is invalid.");
}
if (oct2 >= 0 && oct2 <= 255);{
    System.out.println("Octet two is invalid.");
}
if (oct3 >= 0 && oct3 <= 255);{
    System.out.println("Octet three is invalid.");
}
if (oct4 >= 1 && oct4 <= 254);{
    System.out.println("Octet four is invalid.");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: So, what happened?  I see you need to add a `scan.nextLine();` with no value on the left side after each `scan.nextInt();`  Also, the instructions say incorrect, not invalid.  Finally, you're not printing the IP address.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You wrote in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69592086/i-am-unsure-how-to-list-invalid-octets-if-there-are-others-that-are-valid#comment123007702_69592086): _I see you need to add a `scan.nextLine();` with no value on the left side after each `scan.nextInt();`_ In this instance, that is not required.

Comment: If you want to cause unnecessary trouble, inform your teacher this assignment is wrong because in 4th octet of IPv4 address 0 and 255 CAN BE valid, and some values in 1-254 CAN BE INVALID, but 1st octet 224 or 240 up is NEVER VALID depending on what kind of validity you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mistakes in your code.

1. You have a semicolon, i.e. `;`, after each `if` condition, for example

```java
if (oct1 >= 1 && oct1 <= 255);{
```

This means that when the `if` condition is true, an empty statement will be performed and the line after will always be executed. In other words, it doesn't matter what octet the user enters, the message *Octet one is invalid.* will always be displayed. You need to remove the semicolon.

2. Your `if` condition actually checks whether the octet is valid. You need to change that.
3. Finally, your code is missing the the code that displays the actual IP address when all the entered octets are valid.

The below code contains the corrections.

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the first Octet:");
int oct1;
oct1 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the second Octet:");
int oct2;
oct2 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the third Octet:");
int oct3;
oct3 = scan.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter the fourth Octet:");
int oct4;
oct4 = scan.nextInt();
boolean isValid = true;
if (oct1 < 1 || oct1 > 255) {
    isValid = false;
    System.out.println("Octet one is invalid.");
}
if (oct2 < 0 || oct2 > 255) {
    isValid = false;
    System.out.println("Octet two is invalid.");
}
if (oct3 < 0 || oct3 > 255) {
    isValid = false;
    System.out.println("Octet three is invalid.");
}
if (oct4 < 1 || oct4 > 254) {
    isValid = false;
    System.out.println("Octet four is invalid.");
}
if (isValid) {
    System.out.println("IP Address: " + oct1 + "." + oct2 + "." + oct3 + "." + oct4);
}
```